# Imaginary Base of log Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, soft-question, logarithms

I was curious to see what wolfram alpha would return if I tried inputting a logarithm with an imaginary base, and it gave me something [quite surprising](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28i%2Cx%29) The real part looks almost like $2\theta(-x)$ (with $\theta$ being the heaviside or step function) and the imaginary part looks quite interesting. How does one interpret the graph as well as the relationship $y=\log_i(x)$ or $i^y=x$

Comment: $\log_i(z)=-\frac{2}{\pi}i\log(z)$, so it's just $\log(z)$ with a scaling factor. The step function real part is the imaginary part of $\log(z)$ which wolfram is giving a [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) along the real axis.

Comment: @HeathWinning Can you write that as an answer?